# SOAP field is always return null as value

Tags: java, soap

We have SOAP response and I'm trying to unmarshal this or just getting the value from the namesp1:result field, but I'm always getting the value null, while in the response the value is set to D.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <namesp1:CheckTransactionDetailsResponse xmlns:namesp1="http://www.iesnare.com/dra/api/CheckTransactionDetails">
            <namesp1:result xsi:type="xsd:string">D</namesp1:result>
            <namesp1:reason xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
            <namesp1:trackingnumber xsi:type="xsd:string">646498141355</namesp1:trackingnumber>
            <namesp1:endblackbox xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
            <namesp1:details>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>device.cookie.enabled</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>1</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>device.flash.enabled</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>0</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>device.flash.installed</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>0</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>device.js.enabled</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>0</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>device.os</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>UNKNOWN</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>ipaddress</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>127.0.0.1</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>realipaddress</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>127.0.0.1</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>realipaddress.source</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>subscriber</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>ruleset.rulesmatched</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>0</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
                <namesp1:detail>
                    <namesp1:name>ruleset.score</namesp1:name>
                    <namesp1:value>0</namesp1:value>
                </namesp1:detail>
            </namesp1:details>
        </namesp1:CheckTransactionDetailsResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have used the following code snippets:

1. Get element by tagnameNS, the response is as follows:

   ```
   Name namesp1:result
   Value: null
   ```

Used Java code:

```
    SOAPBody sb = soapResponse.getSOAPBody();
    Document d = sb.extractContentAsDocument();
    NodeList nodeList = d.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.iesnare.com/dra/api/CheckTransactionDetails", "result");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        org.w3c.dom.Node nodeElement = nodeList.item(i);
        System.out.println("Name " + nodeElement.getNodeName());
        System.out.println("Value: " + nodeElement.getNodeValue());
    }
```

2. Unmarshal response to object, which I think is the best way to do this. But then I'm getting the following exception.

   ```
   Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix xsd is not bound to a namespace
   ```

Used Java code:

```
    SOAPBody sb = soapResponse.getSOAPBody();
    Document d = sb.extractContentAsDocument();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(d);
    CheckTransactionDetailsResponse checkTransactionDetailsResponse = (CheckTransactionDetailsResponse) JAXB.unmarshal(source, CheckTransactionDetailsResponse.class);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Result: " + checkTransactionDetailsResponse.getResult());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
```

Can someone help me to find the correct way to get the response, I prefer to use method 2 but I saw something on internet that this is a bug in JAXB.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:
If you read the documentation for `Node`, you will realize that `Node.getNodeValue()` will always return `null` for `Element` nodes (check the table at the top of the page).

The reason is that there is no "value" concept for XML elements; the value as you intend (the letter D) is a child node (a text node) of that element. You must iterate through children nodes, filtering text ones, to get your value.

Method 2:
Here the problem derives from the current JAXB implementation of `DOMSource`. Sparing the details, the reason is that the namespace declaration is present at Envelope level; when you strip the body, that declaration is lost on serialization of that DOM.

To have it back use a combination of `@XmlSchema`and `@XmlNs` annotations in package-info.java of the package containing your schema classes.